# How to express taking paid time-off in a sentence

Tags: phrase-requests

I would like to have a sentence to indicate a person is on two days of paid time-off.

Could I form a sentence like,

> - "He is on two days paid time off."
> - "He is on paid time off for two days".

Please let me know which one is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write

> He is on two days of paid leave.

Comment: +1 Also, FYI long periods of paid-leave (months) are often referred to as `gardening leave`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of leave, you could name it:

> - She’s on vacation for two days.
> - He’s on sick leave for two days.
> - She’s on jury duty for two days.

Having lived (and worked) in the United States for many years,
I believe that most Americans would interpret the above to mean paid leave. 
Beware that other dialects of English might be different. 
For example, I believe that “He’s on holiday for two days.”
would be OK in British English,
but Americans don’t use the word “holiday” that way.

Answer (score -1):

"He's on PTO for two days" works too.